# Can't figure out serialization error in Elasticsearch Python API

Tags: elasticsearch, serialization, elasticsearch-dsl

My code is displayed below.

```
client = Elasticsearch(url, http_auth = (username, password), verify_certs = False, read_timeout=50, terminate_after=25000)

examplename = 'GEOS.fp.asm.inst1_2d_smp_Nx.20180508_1700.V01.nc4'

s = Search(using = client, index = [set_index]).source(['metadata.Filename'])\
.query('match', Filename={examplename})


total = s.count()
```

The error message is:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: ({'query': {'match': {'Filename': set(['GEOS.fp.asm.inst1_2d_smp_Nx.20180508_1700.V01.nc4'])}}}, TypeError("Unable to serialize set(['GEOS.fp.asm.inst1_2d_smp_Nx.20180508_1700.V01.nc4']) (type: <type 'set'>)",))
```

In general, I don't need my search term to match the whole document. So for example if the document is named GEOS.fp.asm.inst1_2d_smp_Nx.20180508_1700.V01.nc4, I want that document to be returned if I query for 20180508.

Comment: Is FileName a field in your document mapping? What is the point of the braces {} around examplename?

Answer (score 0):

in `.query('match', Filename={examplename})` you are passing in a `set` which is not json serializable. I believe it should have been just `.query('match', Filename=examplename)`. Hope this helps!